# Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.11: How to find out if async relationship is empty?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to update an app from Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.9 to 1.0.0-beta.11, and quite a bit seems to have changed. Specifically, I'm running into issues with finding out if a model instance does indeed have an associated model instance.

```
A = DS.Model.extend({
  b: belongsTo('b', { async: true }),
});

B = DS.Model.extend({
  a: belongsTo('a', { async: true }),
});
```

In Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.9, `a.get('b')` would simply return `null` if no associated model is found. That makes it easy to filter by computed property macros.

In Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.11, `a.get('b')` returns a promise, which makes it much harder to use in computed property macros. If the promise is fulfilled and the content of the promise is `null`, there's no associated record. But I have no idea whether it is possible to implement this check inside a `Ember.computed.filter`.

I have quite a few `Ember.computed.filter`s probing quite a few `Ember.isEmpty(a.get('b'))`s, so I'm looking for a good way to check whether an object's async relationship is empty. Am I missing something obvious, like a built-in Ember Data api call? How would you implement such a check, if you need to filter by associated property presence/absence?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer my own question, I got around this by filtering for `Ember.isEmpty(a.get('b.id'))`, b/c I usually deal with persisted records and was able to ship around the edge cases. Sometimes it's so simple… :D

Answer (score 0):

if the related record is just created and `isNew` is `true`, checking the `id` property would also return `null`. In my case this causes unexpected results. How I managed to overcome this is by checking the `content` property instead. For a newly created record this will return the model class, and `null` if the related object is empty.